# Can't print __str__ from the class

Tags: python, string, class, printing, return

I wondered how can I print the class contents of a particular index. I made a class that has all the values of a certain seismic movement and stores each in its own data type.

Here is the class:

```
import re

class Txt_data:
       
    def __init__(self, result):
    
        self.date = result[0]
        self.time = result[1]
        self.latit = result[2]
        self.long = result[3]
        self.depth = result[4]
        self.md = result[5]
        self.ml = result[6]
        self.mw = result[7]
        self.region = result[8]
        self.method = result[9]    
  
    def date(self):
        return self._date

  
    def time(self):
        return self._time

  
    def latit(self):
        return self._latit

  
    def long(self):
        return self._long

  
    def depth(self):
        return self._depth

  
    def md(self):
        return self._md

  
    def ml(self):
        return self._ml

  
    def mw(self):
        return self._mw

  
    def region(self):
        return self._region

  
    def method(self):
        return self._method        

    # This does not work 
    def __str__(self):
        return ('MAG: ' + float(self.ml()) + ' DEPTH: ' + int(self.region()) + ' DATE/TIME: ' + str(self.date()) + ' ' + str(self.time()) + ' LAT: ' + float(self.latit()) + ' LON: ' + float(self.long()))

result = [('2021.12.02', '22:29:24', '36.9605', '28.1775', '13.0', '-.-', '1.5', '-.-', 'KARACA-MARMARIS (MUGLA)', ' Quick')]


print(Txt_data(result))
```

I was trying to print the data using **str** method but it doesn't work.

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/seyfalsultanov/Documents/uni comp 100/comp100-2021f-ps5-seyfalku/main.py", line 73, in <module>
    print(Txt_data(result))
  File "/Users/seyfalsultanov/Documents/uni comp 100/comp100-2021f-ps5-seyfalku/main.py", line 60, in __str__
    print('MAG: ' + float(self.ml()) + ' DEPTH: ' + int(self.region()) + ' DATE/TIME: ' + str(self.date()) + ' ' + str(self.time()) + ' LAT: ' + float(self.latit()) + ' LON: ' + float(self.long()))
AttributeError: Txt_data instance has no __call__ method
```

My question is how to print the string i tried to print using str method in the class.
Thanks very much beforehand.

Comment: Your instance attributes are shadowing the methods of the same name. `self.latit`, for example, is whatever `result[2]` was, not a callable method.

Comment: None of those methods need to exist. Just access the instance attributes directly, and if you ever find a reason to introduce getters, you can replace the instance attributes with properties without breaking your class's public interface.

Comment: In any case, the code posted does not produce that error. I get an `IndexError` on the line `self.time = result[1]`. Replacing `Txt_data(result)` with `Txt_data(result[0])` gives the expected `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you shadowed all your methods with instance attributes, instead of using `_`-prefixed names for the attributes that the method expect.

```
def __init__(self, result):

    self._date = result[0]
    self._time = result[1]
    self._latit = result[2]
    self._long = result[3]
    self._depth = result[4]
    self._md = result[5]
    self._ml = result[6]
    self._mw = result[7]
    self._region = result[8]
    self._method = result[9]
```

However, none of those getters are necessary; just use the instance attributes directly. In `__str__`, use an f-string to perform any necessary type conversions (which you are currently doing wrong; non-`str` values need to be converted to `str` values, not the other way around).

```
class Txt_data:
       
    def __init__(self, result):
    
        self.date = result[0]
        self.time = result[1]
        self.latit = result[2]
        self.long = result[3]
        self.depth = result[4]
        self.md = result[5]
        self.ml = result[6]
        self.mw = result[7]
        self.region = result[8]
        self.method = result[9]    
  
    def __str__(self):
        return f'MAG: {self.ml} DEPTH: {self.region} DATE/TIME: {self.date} {self.time} LAT: {self.latit} LON: {self.long}'



result = ('2021.12.02', '22:29:24', '36.9605', '28.1775', '13.0', '-.-', '1.5', '-.-', 'KARACA-MARMARIS (MUGLA)', ' Quick')
print(Txt_data(result))
```

---

Finally, I would recommend making `__init__` *not* be responsible for splitting up a list. Have it simply take 10 different arguments, and use a dedicated class method to parse a list in a fixed format.

```
class Txt_data:
       
    def __init__(self, date, time, latitude, long, depth, md, ml, mw, region, method):
    
        self.date = date
        self.time = time
        self.latit = latit
        self.long = long
        self.depth = depth
        self.md = md
        self.ml = ml
        self.mw = mw
        self.region = region
        self.method = method

    @classmethod
    def from_list(cls, x):
        if len(x) != 10:
            raise ValueError("Wrong number of elements in list")
        return cls(*x)
  
    def __str__(self):
        return f'MAG: {self.ml} DEPTH: {self.region} DATE/TIME: {self.date} {self.time} LAT: {self.latit} LON: {self.long}'
```